# Life of Sajah bint Al-Harith ibn Suayd

Tags: history

Sajah bint Al-Harith ibn Suayd declared her prophethood during the apostasy movement and even married Musaylimah. However, when Khalid bin walid crushed the movements around Sajah, she converted to Islam. Is there any account of her life after her conversion to Islam ?

Answer (score -1):

she got married to a sahaba the story of her being a muslim and marrying a sahaba is  mentioned in a controversial book
  الروض العاطر في نزهة الخاطر
which is a fifteenth-century sex manual 
I am not sure how authentic is the story, i am sharing what i know i may be wrong

Comment: Is that book really pretending she married one of the sahaba, could you share a quote? None of the known historians said more than that banu Taghlib -Sajah's tribe- decided later to convert to Islam (they seem more close to Christianity) and that she died around 55 a.H. as a good Muslima.